# How To Release Node When You Let Go Ot Screen? Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, touch, sprite-kit

I would like to press down on the screen and a node will be on the screen and when I release it, it will be removed from parent. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks You Very Much

***CODE I HAVE SO FAR***

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"wall"];

        sprite.scale = 0.5;

        sprite.position = location;

        [self addChild:sprite];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The touchesEnded method is called when your finger is no longer touching the screen. You can implement it and add code to remove your sprite. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch ends */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:location];
        if ([sprite.name isEqualToString:@"wall"]) {
            [sprite removeFromParent];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Add this statement to your touchesBegan method

```
    sprite.name = @"wall";
```

Comment: It didn't work its still on the screen with I release it

Answer (score 0):

A universal approach, which removes all nodes, which are off of the screen:

```
- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    for (SKNode *node in self.children) {
        if (node.position.x < 0 || node.position.y < 0 ||
             node.position.x > self.size.width || node.position.y > self.size.height) {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to enhance the code by executing it only once per second, as you don't need it to be executed every time `update:` method gets called.